# Calling to Endpoints from Android

Tags: android, google-app-engine, entity, endpoint

I'm developing an app with android and appEngine. I deployed AppEngine with 2 new Entities: Version and Noticia.
If I make a call from webbrowser to list Noticia the result is a wellformed json with my Noticias.
If I call from Android (with the generated appName-modules) in debug mode everything works fine, but when I make from realease version I can't get anything from my appengine.
I think that is something about auths but I don't want user to authenticate.
I have in api entity declarations clientId and audiences empty.
Thanks in advance,
iniro

UPDATE --> SOLUTION

Finally I found the solution B-)
The problem was my proguard configuration.
I changed my proguard config file for this one, and voilá.
Thanks.

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in C:/Android/android-studio/sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Needed by google-api-client to keep generic types and @Key annotations accessed via reflection

-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

# Needed by google-api-client to keep generic types and @Key annotations accessed via reflection

-keepclassmembers class * {
  @com.google.api.client.util.Key <fields>;
}

-keepattributes Signature,RuntimeVisibleAnnotations,AnnotationDefault

# Needed by Guava

-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe

# See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/guava-discuss/YCZzeCiIVoI
-dontwarn com.google.common.collect.MinMaxPriorityQueue
```

Comment: Could you please let me know the exact change you did ?

Comment: As I say I changed my proguard config file for above.